# How to reference the list of objects variables in Terrraform configuration block or modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How to reference List of objects variables in terraform module block

*Variables.tf*

```
variable "list_views_datasets" {
  description = "List of Views in the Datasets"
  type = list(object({
    dataset_id   = string
    dataset_name = string
    views = list(object({
      view_id        = string,
      query          = string,
      use_legacy_sql = bool,
      labels         = map(string),
    }))
  }))
  default = []
}
```

tfvars:

```
list_views_datasets = [
  {
      dataset_id       = "testservice"
      dataset_name     = "testservice"
      views            =  [
      {
        view_id        = "issue-data",
        use_legacy_sql = false,
        query          = ".test.sql"
        # unfortunately we have to repeat the project id, dataset id and table id in here.
        labels     = {
          env      = "dev"
          billable = "true"
          owner    = "dev"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

*Main.tf*

```
  module "bigquery_views" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/bigquery/google"
  version = "4.3.0"

  depends_on = [module.bigquery]

  for_each       = { for list_view in var.list_views_datasets : list_view.dataset_id => list_view }
  dataset_id     = each.value.dataset_id
  dataset_name   = each.value.dataset_name
  description    = var.views_description
  project_id     = var.project_id
  location       = var.location
  views          = {
    view_id        = each.value.views[view_id]
    labels         = each.value.views[labels]
    query          = file(each.value.views[query])
    use_legacy_sql = each.value.views[use_legacy_sql]

  } 
  dataset_labels = var.dataset_labels

  access = [
    {
      role          = "roles/bigquery.dataOwner"
      special_group = "projectOwners"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Now i am planning to reference the variable in my module block but i am not sure whether i have referenced corretly the views, query,
> labels value in my mobule block

Comment: Which lines throws what error exactly? In what are those statements enclosed? In its current form they do not make much sense because right now the `description` and `for_each` are on the same level.

Comment: @luk2302 - Description is variable defined in variables.tf. foreach block is defined in my configuration file. since in one variable we have defined nested listed of objects. i am not sure how to reference it in configuration file as a key value pair

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you **can't do this**. You have to pass entire `list_views_datasets` into your module as one variable, or use `for_each` at the module level. In the second case you will create multiple modules.